# Sitefinity Ecommerce - is there "Add to Compare" functionality?

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10

I am using Sitefinity 11, I have to show **"Add to Compare"** link under product. Here I am using ProductList Widget.
But I didn't find any tutorial/documentation for this.

Please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no compare functionality for Sitefinity products.

You can add custom code(js) to set a cookie (session or local storage) with the items the user wants to compare.  Then create a custom widget that grabs the cookie (or other) info. and displays the comparison.

Comment: Ok. will be creating one and will let you know how it goes.